# Inherit height from auto height div

Tags: html, css

For some reason the inside div doesn't get the same height as the div where it is inside, even though the height is inherited from it. How to give this div (`insidediv`) the same height as the parent's div?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <div id="insidediv"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    height:auto;
    border:1px solid black;
}

#insidediv {
    border:1px solid red;
    height:inherit;
}
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f7xBr/)</kbd>

Comment: Because your not giving it a defined height. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/f7xBr/1/)

Comment: `auto => inherit auto`, `100px => inherit 100px` http://jsfiddle.net/f7xBr/2/

Comment: Like @Ruddy said, you need to set an actual height to let it inherit. Here is an alterantive way to solve your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/f7xBr/4/

Comment: @Nico useful suggestion, it just depends if OP wants it to cover completely the parent DIV (see? no text selection or links interaction)

Comment: If you make the inside div the same height as the outer div, it will overflow the outer div due to the content above it.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Good point @RokoC.Buljan, this really depends on the usecase. If you just wanted to have a background container (could be :after or :before and not a dedicated html element) you may just add `z-index:-1;` but this just moves the problem. Here is a demo for that: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/f7xBr/12/.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The property `height:inherit;` will make the child have the same `height` value as the parent. In your case `auto` which means it adapts to its content. As `#insidediv` has no content , it's height is 0.

If you want `#insidediv` to have the same height as it's parent (this means it should overlay the content of the parent) you can do this :

```css
#container {
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
#insidediv {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p>Some text</p>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <div id="insidediv"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is any other way to have the above result without relative and absolute position?

Comment: web-tiki thanks for your answer. I use flex-box and my problem solved!